# Converted from .py to .exe but output plots are not displayed

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

Based on input data, I have to generate the plots using python scripting and it was run successfully with plots displayed. Later, unfortunately, after conversion from .py to .exe file, the outputs plots are not generated when clicked on .exe file, What may be the problem with .exe? Does anyone face a similar issue?

Comment: The plots were probably created by your IDE. Does your program have an interface? Do you have a few `fig.show()` missing?

Comment: I have used plt.show(). if we run with a python script, I don't have any issues to generates plots, the only problem I face is.. when converted to .exe file

Comment: Who closed the question? It's pretty clear: matplotlib pop-up windows don't show when using an exe bundled with PyInstaller. Take a look here OP: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17095180/building-python-pylab-matplotlib-exe-using-pyinstaller

Comment: After using degarding to matplotlib 3.1.3 version, the plots are displayed

Answer (score 0):

it could be number of things,
dependencies are not included with the .exe file,
or your program reads from input files that are not in the same directory as the .exe file

run the .exe in the same directory as .py and see if the problem persists.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Azeer. I am giving the input file (.txt) as dynamic. When the .exe is executed, it will ask for the user input file path and then execute it. Even I tried copying the i/p file and .exe at the same location path.